# How to make a phone number in excel clickable on an iPhone?

Tags: ios, excel, vba

i have an Excel-Sheet in which i create phone hyperlinks by vba with the format

tel:+49 1234 56789

(in the actual link there is "%20" included for spaces like this: "tel:+49%201234%2056789"). The hyperlink is working fine and clickable on a Windows PC (e.g. it opens Skype to call the number), but it also has work when I open the Excel file on an Iphone. So if i click on the number it should open the call menu.

So far i have tried using "callto:" instead of "tel:" and different phone number formatting, but nothing worked so far. A short click on an Iphone does nothing, and if I do a long click i can just copy the number.

Comment: See [Apple URL Scheme Reference - Phone Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html) which says `tel:` should work. If it does not work maybe the iPhone Excel App does not support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tel` is the correct protocol to use and it works.

I created a sample Excel file and manually set the link to

```
tel:+49%201234%2056789
```

When the Excel file is opened in Excel for iPhone, tap the cell with the link and then tap `Link`

[image]

Then tap `Open`

[image]

and then tap `Call`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your effort, i just found out my colleague who was testing wasn't using the excel app for IOS but instead another app which doesn't seem to support the tel protocol.